Overwrite character data (untagged text) contained in a specific tag and add to that block another tag, using XSLTPROC
I need to execute XML transformation on some .xml files based on untagged text contained in specific tag. The problem is that although the untagged text is constant, the "activity" node name can vary. Thus, I cannot rely on activity node name, rather I can only rely on the untagged text in the specific tag. The untagged text that I should look for and then replace is:
%%some/Global%%

And the tree of the tags will be always constant and look like this:
ProcessDefinition/activity[name that varies]/config/endpointURL/
If I match this combination of tag tree and untagged text, then and only then I should replace the untagged text to:
%%new/Code%%

And add the ssl block under the endpointURL tag(in the config block):
<ns999:ssl xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/target">
    <ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>true</ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>
    <ns999:cert isRef="true">/.folder</ns999:cert>
</ns999:ssl>

In general speaking ...
The input:
<pd:ProcessDefinition xmlns:pfx6="SOME DATA HERE">
    <pd:activity name="THIS NAME VARIES FROM EACH PROJECT TO PROJECT">
        <pd:x>00</pd:x>
        <pd:y>00</pd:y>
        <config>
            <endpointURL>%%some/Global%%</endpointURL>
        </config>
        <pd:inputBindings>
            SOME UNIMPORTANT DATA
        </pd:inputBindings>
    </pd:activity>
</pd:ProcessDefinition>

The desired output:
<pd:ProcessDefinition xmlns:pfx6="SOME DATA HERE">
    <pd:activity name="THIS NAME VARIES FROM EACH PROJECT TO PROJECT">
        <pd:x>00</pd:x>
        <pd:y>00</pd:y>
        <config>
            <endpointURL>%%new/Code%%</endpointURL>
            <ns999:ssl xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/target">
                <ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>true</ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>
                <ns999:cert isRef="true">/.folder</ns999:cert>
            </ns999:ssl>
        </config>
        <pd:inputBindings>
            SOME UNIMPORTANT DATA
        </pd:inputBindings>
    </pd:activity>
</pd:ProcessDefinition>

I have tried the following:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/test_2"
    xmlns="http://some/xmlns/test_1" 
    xmlns:tc="http://some/xmlns/test_1" exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="endpointURL">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <ns999:ssl xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/target">
                <ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>true</ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>
                <ns999:cert isRef="true">/.folder</ns999:cert>
            </ns999:ssl>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

I cannot find how to filter the endpointURL by untagged text %%some/Global%%?
And, if the ssl node injection will be in the right place after that tag?
Please, any help would be appreciated.

It's not clear what is the problem you are trying to solve. If you know that you want to modify the endpointURL element and add something after it, then use a template that matches endpointURL by its name (as you have now). The name of its ancestor does not play any role here; every other node will be copied as is by the identity transform template.

Also, to add the ssl element after the endpointURL you need to place it after the xsl:copy instruction, not inside it.

If - and only if - you are not sure of the 'endpointURLelement's name (contrary to what you say about the tree being "constant"), you can process it using<xsl:template match="*[.='%%some/Global%%']">`.

Hi Michael, the endpointURL tag can have different values in it, and I want to trigger only those that contain "%%some/Global%%". Thanks for the ssl comment, will fix it. About the tree, yes its constant but the name attribute of the root can vary. I have struggled a little bit with how to filter the specific activity(root of the tree), because of that issue.

If you want to process endpointURL only if it contains the specific text, then use <xsl:template match="endpointURL[.='%%some/Global%%']">. Not sure what you mean by "the name attribute of the root".

It sounds as if you want something like
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/test_2"
    xmlns="http://some/xmlns/test_1" 
    xmlns:tc="http://some/xmlns/test_1" exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="endpointURL[. = '%%some/Global%%']">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <ns999:ssl xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/target">
            <ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>true</ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>
            <ns999:cert isRef="true">/.folder</ns999:cert>
        </ns999:ssl>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Perhaps change <xsl:template match="endpointURL[. = '%%some/Global%%']"> to <xsl:template match="endpointURL[contains(., '%%some/Global%%')]"> if the value is only meant to be part of the endpointURL.
Online fiddle using libxslt/lxml in the browser.
Michael Kay spotted that your sample data in the question suggests a change to the endpointURL so it might well be that you want
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/test_2"
    xmlns="http://some/xmlns/test_1" 
    xmlns:tc="http://some/xmlns/test_1" exclude-result-prefixes="tc">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="endpointURL[. = '%%some/Global%%']">
        <xsl:copy>%%new/Code%%</xsl:copy>
        <ns999:ssl xmlns:ns999="http://some/xmlns/target">
            <ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>true</ns999:strongCipherSuitesOnly>
            <ns999:cert isRef="true">/.folder</ns999:cert>
        </ns999:ssl>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle.

My reading of the requirement is that <xsl:call-template name="identity"/> in your code should be replaced by <endpointURL>%%new/Code%%</endpointURL>

@MichaelKay, I think you are right, I was following the <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/> in the poster's code for <xsl:template match="endpointURL"> where it seemed he wanted to copy the content of the endpointURL. But the sample data with input and output shows a change in the endpointURL. I will edit the answer.

Hi Martin, thank you very much for your response. Indeed, the second example was what I needed. I have learned a lot from both examples. Nice fiddle, by the way!
